# RAILS DELETE BY POLYMORPHISM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table that uses polymorphism to bookmark "AtaPublic" or "AtaObject".

In my destroy, I don't want to delete a "favorite", by the id of `favorites.id` directly, I would like something like this to come from the route: `{{URL}}/favorites/ata_public/2`
that the id of "AtaPublic" or "AtaObject" came to perform the destroy of the favorite, and not the day of the `favorite_id`.

The question is, what should my destroy controller look like? And my params set? That way it deletes by the ID of the favorite.

**FavoritesController**

```rb
def destroy
  if @favorite.destroy
    render json: {success: I18n.t("favorite.destroy.success_message")}, status: 200
  else
    render json: ErrorMessages.new(error: I18n.t("favorite.destroy.error_message"))
      .call, status: 422
  end
end

private

def parent_ata_public
  return AtaPublic.find_by_id(params[:ata_public_id]) if params[:ata_public_id]
end

def parent_ata_object
  return AtaObject.find_by_id(params[:ata_object_id]) if params[:ata_object_id]
end

def set_favorite
  begin
    @favorite = Favorite.where(user: @current_user).find(parent_ata_public)
  rescue
      render json: ErrorMessages.new(error: I18n.t("favorite.not_found.error_message")).call, status: 404
  end
end
```

How would it be to delete by the same ID in the route?
route: {{URL}}/favorites/ata_public/2

img database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX9uD.png

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `ID` in the URL, you are all set.

In the controller, just use [`request.path`](https://gist.github.com/slavikdev/5a203f9d233e107ee1ef4080a84fb42d) and a bit of regex to get the ID you want.